# Prometheus Query losing data with high intervals and periods

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a very simple promQL query:

```
sum(my_metrics)
```

Well, I have the following returns for each period:

- Last 6 Hours: 1058924 (interval 20s)
- Last 12 Hours: 358243 (interval 1m)
- Last 24 Hours: 163049 (interval 2m)

I understand that increase of intervals (because of data points). But this kind of situation gives me a very confusing sum, and a dashboard not reliable.

The big question is: How can I make a correct sum in Grafana/Prometheus without "losing data".

Answer (score 3):

Try `sum(sum_over_time(my_metrics[d]))`, where `d` must be substituted with `6h`, `12h` or `24h` for obtaining the sum of all the metric values over the last 6 hours, 12 hour or 24 hours.

The `sum_over_time(m[d])` is a [rollup function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup-functions), which calculates the sum of raw samples stored in the database on the given lookbehind window `d` before the given `time`, which is passed to [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries). The sum is calculated independently per each time series.

The `sum()` is an [aggregate function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#aggregate-functions), which calculates the sum for points with identical timestamps across multiple time series.

Answer (score 0):

You must first understand that Prometheus and most metric systems are designed for trend of changes, not exact calculations.

In this particular case intervals translate into query steps, and step means the amount to jump between start and end of a range to evaluate the expression, each jump skips some data points and that affects the result.
To get to a more accurate result with still a reasonable performance, you can use recording rules to create hourly and daily roll-ups of your metric with original scrape resolution, and use them in your dashboards.